# Notification does not showing on particular button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have buttons with span class, I m facing a problem to show each span class above particular button. Like this image[image: This]. How can i do this?

```css
.label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f574067864.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<hr>
<div class="container">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
<span class="label label-success">4</span>

<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
<span class="label label-success">5</span>

<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
<span class="label label-success">6</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f574067864.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <style>
    .sub-btn{
        position: relative;
    }
    .sub-btn span{
        position: absolute !important;
        right: 0;
        top: -15px !important;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-default sub-btn" type="submit">Button <span class="label label-success">4</span></button>


    <button class="btn btn-default sub-btn" type="submit">Button <span class="label label-success">5</span></button>


    <button class="btn btn-default sub-btn" type="submit">Button <span class="label label-success">6</span></button>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is also working and i thing you should eligible for confirmed answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add span inside the button

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button<span class="label label-success">4</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button<span class="label label-success">5</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button<span class="label label-success">6</span></button>
</div>
```

and add this css

```
.btn {
  position:relative;
}
.btn>.label {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmxu460L/)

Comment: particular button means ?

Answer (score 1):

Is that you want?? **Edited**

```css
.label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem;
}
.button-label{
  margin-left:-25px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f574067864.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<hr>
<div class="container">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
<span class="label button-label label-success">4</span>

<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
<span class="label button-label label-success">5</span>

<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Button</button>
<span class="label button-label label-success">6</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working, all other design change following  @Ravi sukhadia answer worked

Comment: see i edited try it.. i wrote particular class for that labels and added css to it.